# Solving colluding problem in Shamir's secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

Can setting random indexes (and hiding them from the parties) in Shamir's secret sharing solve the colluding problem?

Here, Colluding problem is defined as if the threshold number of fraud parties combine and recover the secret without the knowledge of the dealer and Indexes are the x-coordinates of their respective shares.

Comment: What's "the colluding problem?".  Is it that $t$ traitors can recover the secret from a $(t, n)$ secret scheme?

Comment: .. in addition to above comment clarify "index". Is it the x coordinate of the share $(x,P(x))$? and LFSRs are inherently insecure, so the random part also needs to be clarified

Comment: That k of n parties working together can recover the shared secret is the whole point of shamir's secret sharing. If you consider that property undesirable, what do you expect to get out of SSS? If you want the dealer to be a required party, why should they give shares to anybody else, instead of simply being the only one to know the secret?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, I know that SSS's whole point is that if `k` out of `n` participants combine they can reconstruct the secret. But there have been multiple extensive research on what happens if the parties cheat (Verifiable Secret Sharing,  multi-party computation secret sharing). My question is if there is some research on how to prevent parties to collude and recombine without the knowledge/permission of the dealer.

Comment: You haven't described what the difference between the desired scenario of combining k secrets without involving the dealer, and the undesired scenario of combining k secrets without involving the dealer is.

Comment: It's just that, How can a dealer make sure that parties do not collude without his knowledge/permission? @CodesInChaos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Colluding problem is defined as if the threshold number of fraud parties combine and recover the secret without the knowledge of the dealer and Indexes are the x-coordinates of their respective shares.

If the requirement is that you insist that the dealer AND $t$ share holders must cooperate to recover the shared secret, here is what you can do to share a secret value $s$:

- Have the dealer select a random value $r$ (which is the same bit length as $s$); he keeps the value $r$ has his share
- Have the dealer generate a $(t, n)$ shared secret instance for the secret $r \oplus s$; distribute those shares.

Now, $t$ share holders (or, for that matter, all $n$ of them) can recover the value $r \oplus s$; however because they have no information on what $r$ may be, they get no information about $s$.

However, if the dealer is part of the recovery process, he knows what $r$ is; that allows the group to recover $s$.

Comment: This is a good method, but is there any way of doing it without the dealer having to remember anything?

Comment: @CipherNewbie: I do not see how; if the dealer has no secret state after the dealing is complete (that is, after that, the parties can model the dealer), I don't see how to prevent them from creating a simulation of the dealer, and so for any protocol or ceremony to generate the shared secret, they would (if interacting with with the dealer is called for) interact with that simulation (rather than the real dealer). hence not having to inform the real dealer.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a good method, but is there any way of doing it without the dealer having to remember anything?

Ultimately the mathematics can't distinguish between legtimate reconstruction of the secret and malicious reconstruction of the secret. If a group of participants is able to reconstruct the secret legitimately then that same group of participants is able to reconstruct it maliciously. If they dealer can't remember anything then they are not a meaningful participant in the reconstruction.